# Default constructor with normal constructors for classes c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-constructor

I have been trying to understand the default constructor and i think i get it if it's the only constructor in the class. But what if i have more than one constructor defined in the class. What i am trying to do is to create a class "vector", which would store two dimensional vectors. I need one constructor to set the coordinates to the values given in  the main function. I also need a default constructor, which when called, would set the coordinates to 0. I can't seem to figure out how to make both work in the same code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Vector {
    double x_coord, y_coord;
public:
Vector(double x_coord=0, double y_coord=0); //default contructor???

Vector (double x, double y) //normal constructor
{
    set_values (x,y);
}
void set_values(double new_x, double new_y) //function to set values for the vectors
    {
        x_coord=new_x;
        y_coord=new_y;
    }
   double get_x()
    {
        return x_coord;
    }
   double get_y()
    {
        return y_coord;
    }

};
```

Comment: Either have a single constructor `Vector(double x_coord=0, double y_coord=0);` which works both as a default constructor as it can be called with no arguments, and as a two-parameter constructor; or else two constructors, one taking no parameters, as in `Vector()`, and one taking two, `Vector (double x, double y)`. It doesn't make sense to have a constructor that always takes two arguments, as well as one that optionally takes those same arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine constructing objects of the class using the following:

```
Vector v1;         // Construct with x = 0, y = 0
Vector v2(10);     // Construct with x = 10, y = 0
Vector v3(10, 20); // Construct with x = 10, y = 20
```

You can accomplish all of that with just one constructor:

```
Vector(double x=0, double y=0) : x_coord(x), y_coord(y) {}
```

You don't need the second constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems like a very neat way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor is the constructor invoked when you omit the parantheses when defining an instance of the `class`. Example:

```
Vector vec;
```

Here, the default constructor (`Vector::Vector(double = 0, double = 0)`) is executed.

You can remove the other constructor (`Vector::Vector(double, double)`) and use this definition for the default constructor:

```
Vector(double x_coord = 0, double y_coord = 0) {
    set_values(x_coord, y_coord);
}
```

When you pass two arguments, this will be called automatically. Furthermore, an ambiguity is resolved: what if, with those two constructors, you passed two `double`s? Which one of them should be called? The compiler would raise an error saying that the constructors are ambiguous.

---

Notes:

- The `set_values` function does not seem helpful as it does not do any useful work. Use a member initializer list in the constructor instead to improve performance. Also, it is considered good style:

  ```
  Vector(double x_coord = 0, double y_coord = 0): x_coord(x_coord), y_coord(y_coord) { }
  ```
- Your extensive use of setters and getters looks... bad. It breaks encapsulation. Provide functions, which do not expose implementation details but perform useful operations such as `move`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i figured it all out.
If anyone needs the answer:
You can have the default and other constructors defined in Class

```
class Vector {
double x_coord, y_coord;
public:
Vector():  x_coord(0), y_coord(0) {};   //default constructor

Vector (double x, double y) //normal constructor
{
    set_values (x,y);
}
```

it's just the way you define your default constructor.

Comment: It's feasible with just one constructor. Look at the answers!